# Tomcat GC: two machines with the same settings behave differently

Tags: java, tomcat, garbage-collection

I have two virtual servers (Win 2012R2) with the same configs: 64GB memory and 12 cores.

Each virtual server has a Tomcat instance (8.0.36) and they clustered through SimpleTcpCluster.

Regarding the GC, I am using the following for both:

```
set JAVA_OPTS=-Xms4g 
set JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Xmx4g
set JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Xss256k
set JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=2000
set JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -XX:G1HeapRegionSize=8
set JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -XX:ParallelGCThreads=8 -XX:ConcGCThreads=4 
set JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -verbose:gc -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps
```

One Tomcat instance performs very well and I never see any noticeable slowness in performance. I do see it often does GC. Here is a sample data it produced:

```
2016-07-22T09:55:57.164-0400: 36257.947: [GC pause (G1 Evacuation Pause) (young), 0.0408534 secs]
   [Parallel Time: 11.9 ms, GC Workers: 8]
      [GC Worker Start (ms): Min: 36257947.8, Avg: 36257948.0, Max: 36257948.2, Diff: 0.3]
      [Ext Root Scanning (ms): Min: 0.6, Avg: 1.0, Max: 2.4, Diff: 1.8, Sum: 8.0]
      [Update RS (ms): Min: 0.6, Avg: 1.8, Max: 2.1, Diff: 1.4, Sum: 14.4]
         [Processed Buffers: Min: 11, Avg: 16.3, Max: 21, Diff: 10, Sum: 130]
      [Scan RS (ms): Min: 0.7, Avg: 0.9, Max: 1.0, Diff: 0.2, Sum: 7.3]
      [Code Root Scanning (ms): Min: 0.0, Avg: 0.2, Max: 0.3, Diff: 0.3, Sum: 1.2]
      [Object Copy (ms): Min: 7.2, Avg: 7.5, Max: 7.7, Diff: 0.5, Sum: 59.7]
      [Termination (ms): Min: 0.1, Avg: 0.1, Max: 0.1, Diff: 0.0, Sum: 0.9]
         [Termination Attempts: Min: 324, Avg: 360.5, Max: 388, Diff: 64, Sum: 2884]
      [GC Worker Other (ms): Min: 0.0, Avg: 0.1, Max: 0.2, Diff: 0.2, Sum: 1.0]
      [GC Worker Total (ms): Min: 11.4, Avg: 11.6, Max: 11.7, Diff: 0.3, Sum: 92.6]
      [GC Worker End (ms): Min: 36257959.4, Avg: 36257959.5, Max: 36257959.6, Diff: 0.2]
   [Code Root Fixup: 0.3 ms]
   [Code Root Purge: 0.0 ms]
   [Clear CT: 0.8 ms]
   [Other: 27.8 ms]
      [Choose CSet: 0.0 ms]
      [Ref Proc: 23.0 ms]
      [Ref Enq: 0.2 ms]
      [Redirty Cards: 0.2 ms]
      [Humongous Register: 0.2 ms]
      [Humongous Reclaim: 0.4 ms]
      [Free CSet: 3.0 ms]
   [Eden: 2406.0M(2406.0M)->0.0B(2401.0M) Survivors: 51.0M->56.0M Heap: 2809.2M(4096.0M)->211.6M(4096.0M)]
 [Times: user=0.06 sys=0.00, real=0.06 secs]
```

The other Tomcat, however, constantly shows slowness. It gets back to normal performance after a while of slowness each time. Here is the sample data it produces in GC:

```
2016-07-22T10:03:22.442-0400: 37959.345: [GC pause (G1 Evacuation Pause) (young), 0.1030285 secs]
   [Parallel Time: 50.4 ms, GC Workers: 8]
      [GC Worker Start (ms): Min: 37959345.4, Avg: 37959345.5, Max: 37959345.6, Diff: 0.2]
      [Ext Root Scanning (ms): Min: 0.4, Avg: 1.2, Max: 5.2, Diff: 4.8, Sum: 9.8]
      [Update RS (ms): Min: 0.0, Avg: 0.0, Max: 0.0, Diff: 0.0, Sum: 0.0]
         [Processed Buffers: Min: 0, Avg: 0.0, Max: 0, Diff: 0, Sum: 0]
      [Scan RS (ms): Min: 0.1, Avg: 0.4, Max: 0.5, Diff: 0.4, Sum: 3.2]
      [Code Root Scanning (ms): Min: 0.0, Avg: 7.5, Max: 15.1, Diff: 15.1, Sum: 59.6]
      [Object Copy (ms): Min: 33.6, Avg: 40.6, Max: 48.2, Diff: 14.6, Sum: 325.1]
      [Termination (ms): Min: 0.0, Avg: 0.3, Max: 0.4, Diff: 0.4, Sum: 2.3]
         [Termination Attempts: Min: 1, Avg: 880.9, Max: 1086, Diff: 1085, Sum: 7047]
      [GC Worker Other (ms): Min: 0.0, Avg: 0.1, Max: 0.2, Diff: 0.1, Sum: 0.9]
      [GC Worker Total (ms): Min: 50.0, Avg: 50.1, Max: 50.3, Diff: 0.3, Sum: 400.8]
      [GC Worker End (ms): Min: 37959395.5, Avg: 37959395.6, Max: 37959395.6, Diff: 0.1]
   [Code Root Fixup: 8.7 ms]
   [Code Root Purge: 0.0 ms]
   [Clear CT: 0.8 ms]
   [Other: 43.1 ms]
      [Choose CSet: 0.0 ms]
      [Ref Proc: 36.5 ms]
      [Ref Enq: 1.2 ms]
      [Redirty Cards: 0.2 ms]
      [Humongous Register: 0.1 ms]
      [Humongous Reclaim: 0.0 ms]
      [Free CSet: 4.3 ms]
   [Eden: 2300.0M(2300.0M)->0.0B(2346.0M) Survivors: 157.0M->111.0M Heap: 2496.5M(4096.0M)->150.5M(4096.0M)]
 [Times: user=0.42 sys=0.00, real=0.11 secs]
```

What could be the reason for this difference in performance? I really have no idea where to start with. If you need any info about the system, please feel free to ask.

Regards.

**Updates**

Here is more system info:

- Both instances run the same public-facing website (exactly same code).
- There is a Kemp load balancer in front of the two instances. The method is round
  robin.
- Same Java version: 1.8.0.92 (verified again)
- The load on both instances should be very similar.
- The website is not in the cloud.
- This a newly launched website with low traffic. Averagely 10 - 20 visitors at any point. With this low traffic, the slowness still happens.
- The two Tomcat instances sit on two boxes.
- On the box with slow Tomcat instance, I have a passive SQL server 2014 instance, which is clustered with the active SQL server 2014 instance on the other box where the fast Tomcat instance sits.
- The communication between the two boxes is 10G.

Comment: Are they serving different types of traffic? Is the work distribution even? You need to start by verifying that they are both being given equal amounts of work.  The GC and performance info is meaningless without workload context.  A heart rate of 140 and BP of 220/110 is a serious problem until you discover the subject is in the middle of a marathon.

Comment: Just some thoughts, hope both of them uses exactly the same java version? Are they load balanced? if yes is one taking more load than the other?

Comment: Jim and Isiva, thanks so much for chiming in! I updated the post with additional system info. Again, thanks!

Comment: Hard to say from one GC entry if there is a difference (refproc). You could compare "-XX:+PrintFlagsFinal" settings. Do the machines show same ram-free and swap usage numbers when tomcat is terminated? Is balooning used? different memory reservations on the host?

Comment: eckes, thanks for your questions. If I use "-XX:+PrintFlagsFinal", will I be able to get the data that answers all your questions?

Answer (score 3):

As you are using virtual machines, it is likely that there are “neighbors” that run on the same hardware capacity. These neighbors could steal capacity from your virtual machine. For example, in Amazon, in case of conflict of resources allocation, at first the priority goes to a larger instance (c4.xlarge will get resources firstly as compared to t1.micro, so at t1.micro you will see `steal time` at `top` utility). In my practice when I had similar situations I stopped and started slow instance, and it moves to another hardware. If this time, it is lucky with “neighbors”, the steal time would be absent (it works with Amazon, but I suppose it is applicable to other hypervisor). What provider are you using?

Comment: valch85, thanks so much for sharing your thoughts. I updated the post with new system info. Thanks, again!

Answer (score 1):

I would say 2 things to answer your worries:

- I don't think you are experiencing a slowdown; We are talking 0.06 vs 0.11 seconds; The breakdown between **Eden** and **Survivors** shows that those were 2 different collections. One cleared Eden and Survivors, while the other cleared Eden, but promoted some of the objects to Survivors (Survivors size increased by GC in the 1st collection). Perhaps the promotion is quicker than memory clean...
- You write that:

  > The load on both instances should be very similar.

... but how can you be sure? Unless you can fire pairs of identical requests (for load balancer to give one to 1st instance, and the other to the 2nd one) you cannot be sure.

The dynamism of the whole stack, and the behaviour of both the clients and the servers will differ. Since as you say the website is low volume, the differences can be bigger as the averaging effect is smaller.

Small local fluctuations at micro level can differ by a lot so one snapshot GC can show just that, while on macro level little variations eventually add up leading to different things needing cleaning.

Comment: Thanks so much for helping me! Is there any change you would like me to make to the system? Regarding the slow server, it takes 21 seconds to load a particular page. It constant exhibits this slowness.  The other server's response is almost always instant for the same page. Again, thanks for help!

Comment: are both servers contacting the active SQL Server instance? I think that the picture big and incomplete to be sure.  Keep probing,  look at the system logs,  resources utilisation in task manager... there are so many avenues to explore

Comment: Yes,  both servers point to the active SQL Server instance. Thanks for your suggestions!